# tikz-uml sequence diagram "Extra \or" error

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, diagrams

I was compiling the following code which uses the [`tikz-uml`](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{pgf}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{umlseqdiag}
        \umlobject{a}
        \begin{umlcall}{a}{a}
            \begin{umlcall}{a}{a}           % line 11
            \end{umlcall}                   % line 12
        \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It compiles on one machine without any problems.
<strike>However, on another one, it gives an error.</strike>
Both machines use Windows 7 64-bit, MikTeX 2.9 64-bit.
Error message:

```
! Extra \or.
\ifthenelse #1->\toks@ {#1}\TE@repl \or
                                        \TE@or \TE@repl \and \TE@and \TE@rep...
l.12            \end{umlcall}
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
```

Anyone knows the reason for it and how to resolve it?
I know it's due to an `umlcall` environment inside another one.
It's actually enough to uncomment lines 11 and 12 to make the error disappear, but the result is not the same obiously.

The problem doesn't depend on including PGF or TikZ packages, nor on defining `inputenc` or `fontenc`.
It doesn't depend on the fact that the `a` object calls itself neither.

**EDIT 1:**
I was mistaken, the code that I tested and that worked on other machine was actually a bit different (precisely: everything inside the `tikzpicture` environment was a part of a bigger file).

**The solution is to add `\usepackage[language]{babel}` in the preamble.**
But why does the documentation not say anything about it...?

**EDIT 2:**
The wanted result is:

[image: tikz-uml nested self-umlcall]

Comment: About tags: I wanted to add [tikz-uml] tag, but it doesn't exist and I can't do this on my own.

Comment: You need to include a diagram of what you expect your code to produce. As it is, it looks like everything is referring to the same object, i.e. the nested umlcall is probably a mistake.

Comment: Please read the question carefully, a nested umlcall is NOT a mistake. The same error appears when there are two `umlobject`s.

Comment: @Curdeius: Please include the diagram. I'd be interested to see what the successful compilation yields. In addition, we need version numbers on the tikz-uml package that you are using for each machine, since a difference would be one probable cause of success on one machine and not the other.

Comment: In fact, I'd like to know if both distributions are fully up to date. This package depends on other packages and that is also a potential cause of this difference.

Comment: I've tried it and it appears to be broken back to 0.9.1. I suspect this is coming from an incompatible change in some other package, not tikz-uml.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough : you were quite right, see the edited question

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I can't add images, because I've got not enough reputation points. The diagram is really simple, it presents an `a` object that calls itself, then calls itself again, returns from the second call (dashed line), and returns from the second call (dashed line).

Comment: You can include images as usual and remove the preceding `!` from the image link. Users with edit privileges will correct this. Regardless, we'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to use the `babel` package with the language of your choice, i.e. add one line to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

Of course, you can change `english` to use different language.

The documentation of the `tikz-uml` package says nothing about this issue, nothing like "required packages" is mentioned there.

**UPDATE:**
I have removed the necessity of loading `babel` package by modifying the file `tikz-uml.sty`.
Indeed, the problem is somewhere in the definition of `umlcall` environment and the cause is `\ifthenelse` command.
I have therefore changed the line 3397 from:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlCallStartNodeName}{\tikzumlCallEndNodeName}}{%
```

to

```
\ifstrequal{\tikzumlCallStartNodeName}{\tikzumlCallEndNodeName}{%
```

after having added the following line to the beginning of the package file:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
```

I have also performed a similar modification in the line 3403, obtaining:

```
  \ifstrequal{\tikzumlcallreturn}{tikzumlEmpty}{%
```

Comment: Actually, this is mentioned on the home page.
"For still unknown reasons, TikZ-UML works fine if you have already included the babel package with the language of your choice."
http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en&id=doc#t-0.1.2