# Countability of the rationals: a pictorial diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, matrices, tikz-matrix

I am trying to reproduce the diagram below:

[image]

I'm wondering what I should use to generate this. I can make the matrix, that's simple, but getting the arrows right is what's difficult... It would be interesting to use [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/graph/), where the S_{ij}'s are circled nodes, and then some nodes just aren't connected, and the ellipses and the S_i:'s are nodes, but they wouldn't be circled. I'm looking [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/labeled-chain/), and I think this would work too, but I don't yet know how to interpret the (m-i-j) symbolism, or how to connect arrows to nodes.

---

So far, I've got the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

\node[main node] (1) {$S_{11}$};
\node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {$S_{12}$};
\node[main node] (3) [below of=1] {$S_{21}$};
\node[main node] (4) [below of=3] {$S_{31}$};
\node[main node] (5) [below of=2] {$S_{22}$};
\node[main node] (6) [right of=2] {$S_{13}$};
\node[main node] (7) [right of=6] {$S_{14}$};
\node[main node] (8) [below of=6] {$S_{23}$};
\node[main node] (9) [below of=5] {$S_{32}$};
\node[main node] (10) [below of=4] {$S_{41}$};

\node[main node] (11) [right of=10] {$S_{42}$};
\node[main node] (12) [right of=11] {$S_{43}$};
\node[main node] (13) [right of=12] {$S_{44}$};
\node[main node] (14) [right of=9] {$S_{33}$};
\node[main node] (15) [right of=14] {$S_{34}$};
\node[main node] (16) [right of=8] {$S_{24}$};

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(1) edge node [right] {} (2)
(2) edge node [right] {} (3)
(3) edge node [right] {} (4)
(4) edge node [right] {} (5)
(5) edge node [right] {} (6)
(6) edge node [right] {} (7)
(7) edge node [right] {} (8)
(8) edge node [right] {} (9)
(9) edge node [right] {} (10);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe a commutative diagram would be better...

Comment: How do you get rid of the circles?

Comment: To get rid of the circles, remove `circle,fill=blue!20,draw`.

Comment: What is the question now? You can certainly make this diagram in another way. A `\matrix` or even `tikz-cd` come to mind. You could also simplify the connecting of the nodes or creating the matrix.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Qrrbrbirlbel commented, you can use the `\matrix` command. The `matrix of math nodes` option from the `matrix` library will save you some typing by automatically turning on math mode in each cell. When you name a matrix `(m)`, you can use the syntax `(m-i-j)` to refer to the cell in row `i` and column `j` of that matrix. To connect nodes, simply draw the edges after the matrix is set up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,column sep=1cm,row sep=1cm]{
    s_{11} & s_{12} & s_{13} & s_{14} & \cdots \\
    s_{21} & s_{22} & s_{23} & s_{24} & \cdots \\
    s_{31} & s_{32} & s_{33} & s_{34} & \cdots \\
    s_{41} & s_{42} & s_{43} & \cdots \\
};

\draw[->]
         (m-1-1)edge(m-1-2)
         (m-1-2)edge(m-2-1)
         (m-2-1)edge(m-3-1)
         (m-3-1)edge(m-2-2)
         (m-2-2)edge(m-1-3)
         (m-1-3)edge(m-1-4)
         (m-1-4)edge(m-2-3)
         (m-2-3)edge(m-3-2)
         (m-3-2)edge(m-4-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any option in the "matrix" command that allows to draw circles around the nodes?

Comment: @boumol: try `nodes={circle,draw}`; `nodes` sets the style for every node in the matrix, `circle` specifies the shape of the nodes, and `draw` draws the border of the nodes. You may also add keys like `inner sep=<num>` or `minimum size=<num>` to make node sizes uniform

Comment: @KevinC This one is the slickest. The rainbow guy's is good too. `:-)`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that draws the edges automatically; no need to specify them one by one!

You can make the graph as big as you wish: simply specify the number of nodes you want by changing the value of positive integer `\N`.

Note: Failure to load the `babel` package with the `english` option will generate errors. See [tikz-uml sequence diagram "Extra \or" error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44768/21891) for more details.

**Edit**: See also [Qrrbrbirlbel's "chains" solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129491/21891), which is similar to mine in spirit.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
[
    ->,
    >=stealth',
    scale=2,
    auto,
  thick,
  main node/.style=%
  {
%   circle,
%   fill=blue!20,
%   draw,
    font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries,
  }
]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\N{10}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\i{1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{1}

\node[main node] at (\j,-\i) (n1) {$S_{\i\j}$};

\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \current in {1,2,...,\N-1}%
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\next{\current+1}
    \ifnum\i=1% (first row)
        \ifnumodd{\j}%
        {   % Go East
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\j+1}
        }{% Go South West
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\i{\i+1}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\j-1}
        }
    \else% 
        \ifnum\j=1% (first column)
            \ifnumodd{\i}%
            { % Go North East
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\i{\i-1}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\j+1}
            }{% Go South
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\i{\i+1}
            }
        \else
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ijsum}{\i+\j}
            \ifnumodd{\ijsum}%
            { % Go South West
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\i{\i+1}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\j-1}
            }{% Go North East
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\i{\i-1}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\j+1}
            }
        \fi
    \fi
    \node[main node] at (\j,-\i) (n\next) {$S_{\i\j}$};
    \draw (n\current) -- (n\next);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for your edit, but it may lead future visitors to believe I'm competent with the `chains` library, which is not true  at all. Why not put that in your post rather than mine?

Comment: Alright, the solution I added is very similar to your solutions which seemed to be a better fit. But after all, the edit button is there and it is also wiki and such …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I just don't want to mislead future visitors as to what I'm familiar with. I appreciate the intention, but I think that alternative of yours rightfully belongs in your answer. We can always refer to each other's solutions in the text.

Answer (score 5):

## Matrix

It seems that a TikZ `\matrix` is the easiest approach here.

Combined with the `execute at empty cell` which fills the matrix automatically and the `continous edges to` style, you can create this diagram very fast.

Though, the arrows follow a pattern which can be automated, too:
This is done with the keys `matrix connector urr` (up-right, right) and `matrix connector ldd` (left-down, down) which initial a search algorithm that relies on named nodes in the matrix.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  @continous edges to/.style={insert path={edge (#1) (#1)}},
  continous edges to/.style={@continous edges to/.list={#1}},
  matrix connector urr/.code args={#1-#2-#3}{%
    \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1-\the\numexpr#2-1\relax-\the\numexpr#3+1\relax}{%
      \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1-#2-\the\numexpr#3+1\relax}{}{
        \tikzset{insert path={(#1-#2-#3) edge (#1-#2-\the\numexpr#3+1\relax)},
                 matrix connector ldd/.expanded={#1-#2-\the\numexpr#3+1\relax}}%
      }%
    }{%
      \tikzset{insert path={(#1-#2-#3) edge (#1-\the\numexpr#2-1\relax-\the\numexpr#3+1\relax)},
               matrix connector urr/.expanded={#1-\the\numexpr#2-1\relax-\the\numexpr#3+1\relax}}%
    }
  },
  matrix connector ldd/.code args={#1-#2-#3}{%
    \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1-\the\numexpr#2+1\relax-\the\numexpr#3-1\relax}{%
      \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1-\the\numexpr#2+1\relax-#3}{}{%
        \tikzset{insert path={(#1-#2-#3) edge (#1-\the\numexpr#2+1\relax-#3)},
                 matrix connector urr/.expanded={#1-\the\numexpr#2+1\relax-#3}}%
      }%
    }{%
      \tikzset{insert path={(#1-#2-#3) edge (#1-\the\numexpr#2+1\relax-\the\numexpr#3-1\relax)},
               matrix connector ldd/.expanded={#1-\the\numexpr#2+1\relax-\the\numexpr#3-1\relax}}%
    }
  },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={
    shape=circle,
    inner sep=+.1667em,% half the default value
  },
  execute at empty cell={\node {$S_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}$};},
  row sep=2em,
  column sep=2em
] {
  & & & \\
  & & & \\
  & & & \\
  & & & \\
};
\path[->, ultra thick, matrix connector urr={m-1-1}];
\path[->,white, shorten >=2\pgflinewidth] (m-1-1) [continous edges to={m-1-2, m-2-1, m-3-1, m-2-2, m-1-3, m-1-4, m-2-3, m-3-2, m-4-1}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Chains

An alternative approach, similar to Jubobs' answer, can be implemented with the `chains` library where one can use the placement options of the `positioning` library (i.e. `on grid`, `node distance`) for greater control. It is only used to place the nodes that are connected.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\newcommand*{\subscript}[3][]{%
    \ifodd#2
      \the\numexpr#2+1-#3\relax#1#3%
    \else
      #3#1\the\numexpr#2+1-#3\relax
    \fi}
\tikzset{
  zigzag/.code 2 args={%
    \ifnum#1>1
      \ifodd#1
        \ifnum#2=1
          \def\position{below}%
        \else
          \def\position{above right}%
        \fi
      \else
        \ifnum#2=1
          \def\position{right}%
        \else
          \def\position{below left}%
        \fi
      \fi
      \tikzset{\position=of \tikzchainprevious}
    \fi
  },
  zigzag*/.code={%
    \edef\llevel{\number\tikzchaincount}%
    \pgfmathloop
      \edef\testllevel{\the\numexpr\llevel-\pgfmathcounter\relax}%
      \ifnum1>\testllevel\relax
        \let\level\pgfmathcounter
      \else
        \let\llevel\testllevel
    \repeatpgfmathloop
    \tikzset{zigzag=\level\llevel}%
  }
}
%
\tikzset{
  every label/.append style={inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, font=\tiny},
  label position=above left,
  every join/.append style={-latex},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain=ch going {zigzag=\level\llevel},
  node distance=.75cm and 1cm,
  every on chain/.append style={
    join, label={(\number\tikzchaincount)}}]
\foreach \level in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \llevel in {1,...,\level}
    \node[on chain=ch] {$S_{\subscript[,]\level\llevel}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  on grid, node distance=1cm and 1.5cm, start chain=ch placed zigzag*,
  every on chain/.append style={
    circle, inner sep=+.1667em, text depth=+0pt, text height=+1.5ex,
    join, label/.expanded={(\noexpand\subscript[/]{\level}{\llevel})}}]
\foreach \cnt in {a,...,f} \node[on chain=ch] {\cnt};
\foreach \cnt in {G,...,M} \node[on chain=ch] {\cnt};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]